# iptables mangle, DROP everything except certain IPs

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm running `CentOS` with `iptables` and have the following to block internal traffic between servers:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 100.64.0.0/10 -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

But I would like to allow traffic between `100.65.1.2` and `10.80.1.1`.

How can I add that one exception?

Comment: You could always insert a specific ACCEPT rule _before_ your DROP rule, as iptables is a "first-match" implementation of a firewall.

Comment: Also, why do you use the `mangle` table?

Comment: Which table would you recommend instead of `mangle`?

Comment: The default `INPUT` or `OUTPUT` for example, but it doesn't really matter, I'm just curios. Did you work out your exception?